# How to uniquely identify image in Windows Phone Image Library?

Tags: c#, windows, image, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to uniquely identify an image in Windows Phone 8 Image Library ?
I want to check if an image exists in user's Library and if not let the user save this image. At this time i have solution that merely works by checking the name and Date the image was taken. There is however the possibility two images have the same name and date taken.

Comment: You could checksum it in some way, and compare checksums. (Or compute a hash - same thing.) You'd need to read the image's bytes to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it it will work or not but atleast worth a try.
[BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363788(v=vs.85).aspx).
Another link to support that might help, [compare two files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/09/22/to-compare-two-filenames-lucian-wischik.aspx). The second link is in VB, if you know a little bit of VB, you can convert to C#

Comment: Unfortunately BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION is not supported in Windows Phone 8. Thank you anyway

Comment: I am doing the same thing with music files on sd card in windows phone, Thanks for cofirming. I was going to break my head over that.